# Kimono Scrape Remains "In Progress"

Tags: google-sheets, scrape, kimono

I am having issues with Kimono Labs. Every scrape I run will run indefinitely without throwing an error or completing. Occasionally, the scrapes will randomly start working days in the future without any changes on my behalf - only to fail a few days later. I love Kimono because it is so easy to integrate with Google Sheets for friends to alter the data, but this has become problematic. There doesn't seems to be any related help in the Kimono help data for an issue such as this.

One of my scrapes is not behind a paywall and the other is. One is set to run daily and the one behind the paywall is set to run hourly.

What steps can I take to troubleshoot this error and get the ball rolling again?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very simple API doing the exact same thing for weeks!

I'm only using a free account so I didn't have any support but I ended up sending a bug report at https://www.kimonolabs.com/support .

Strangely enough, the very next day, the API started working normally again (and has ever since). I assume they looked into it and fixed whatever was stopping my crawl from completing.